# Building a class to use `with` to establish exclusive sql connections

Tags: python, with-statement

I am working on a simple convenience class to use with the `with` operator so that I can establish exclusive access to a sqlite3 database for a extended writing session in a concurrent system.

Here is the class:

```
import sqlite3 as sql

class ExclusiveSqlConnection(object):
    """meant to be used with a with statement to ensure proper closure"""
    def __enter__(self, path):
        self.con = sql.connect(path, isolation_level = "EXCLUSIVE")
        self.con.execute("BEGIN EXCLUSIVE")
        self.cur = self.con.cursor()
        return self

    def __exit__(self):
        self.con.commit()
        self.con.close()
```

However, when I run this I get the error:

```
with sql_lib.ExclusiveSqlConnection(self.output) as c:
TypeError: object.__new__() takes no parameters
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The constructor (`__init__` method) for your `ExclusiveSqlConnection` needs to take a `path` parameter.

On the other hand, `__enter__` takes no parameter other than `self`.

```
import sqlite3 as sql

class ExclusiveSqlConnection(object):
    """meant to be used with a with statement to ensure proper closure"""

    def __init__(self, path):
        self.path = path

    def __enter__(self):
        self.con = sql.connect(self.path, isolation_level = "EXCLUSIVE")
        self.con.execute("BEGIN EXCLUSIVE")
        self.cur = self.con.cursor()
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exception_type, exception_val, trace):
        self.con.commit()
        self.con.close()
```